# Intergal of 2 torus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

> Let $F: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^3$ be given as
> $$(\theta,\phi) \mapsto ((2+\cos \phi)\cos \theta,(2+\cos\phi)\sin\theta,\sin\phi).$$
> Let $M$ be the two torus obtained as the image of $F$.
> Consider the $2-$form $\omega=x \, dy \wedge dz$, compute $F^*\omega$ and use this to compute $\int_M \omega$.

**Attempt:**

As $M$ is orientation preserving, by a proposition in Lee,

$$\int_M \omega = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}F^* \omega.$$

I calculated $F^* \omega$ to be

$$F^* \omega = (2 \cos \phi + \cos^2 \phi)\cos^2 \theta \, d \theta \wedge d \phi$$

thus

\begin{align}
\int_M \omega&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} (2\cos \phi + \cos^2 \phi)\cos^2 \theta d \theta d \phi\\
&=5\pi^2.
\end{align}

Is my work correct?

For the pullback I did this:

\begin{align}
F^*\omega&=F^*(x \, dy \wedge dz)\\
&=((2+\cos \phi)\cos \theta)\, d((2+\cos\phi)\sin\theta) \wedge d(\sin\phi)\\
&=(2+\cos\phi)\cos\theta(-\sin\phi\sin\theta\, d \phi + \cos \theta (2+\cos\phi)\, d \theta) \wedge \cos \phi \, d \phi
\end{align}

and the $d \phi \wedge d \phi$ cancels so its

$$(2+\cos\phi)^2 \cos^2 \theta \cos \phi\, d \theta \wedge d \phi$$

Comment: You did not show enough work. But the pullback looks implausible and the answer is wrong.

Comment: @TedShifrin is my pullback correct now ?

Comment: And I get $4\pi^2$ as my result.

Comment: Looks much better!

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks!! I had forgotten to square the $(2+\cos\phi)$ term!!